# Overlaying the same line plot in every facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, facet-wrap

I need to overlay the same **'target_gene'** plot on all facets. I can overlay it easily if I plot everything in 1 panel. However, when I combine this action with the `facet_wrap`, the **'target_gene'** is plotted in a separate facet, rather than being overlaid on other plots. Please see the script below. The **'select_genes_plot'** works (see [same panel plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwtfU.png)) but the **'select_genes_plot_facet'** doesn't work (see [plot in facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwtZt.png)).

Please not that I cannot use `+annotate(geom='point',x=target_gene$gene_exp.Time,y=target_gene$gene_exp.Value)` because I also want to plot the sd error bars.

The transcriptome_reshape and target_gene data look like this, please see [transcriptome data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JneRH.png), and [target gene data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3jUu.png))

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

##1. Read transcriptome dataset
setwd('./')
transcriptome_data <- read.csv ('./Kaladp_expression_FPKM_average_sd.csv', header = TRUE)
reshape_data <- melt(transcriptome_data)  #the function melt reshapes it from wide to long
average_geneexpression <- reshape_data[1:(743136/2),]
sd_geneexpression <- reshape_data[((743136/2)+1):743136,]
transcriptome_reshape <- cbind(average_geneexpression, sd_geneexpression)

colnames(transcriptome_reshape)[2]<- 'gene_exp.Time'
colnames(transcriptome_reshape)[3]<- 'gene_exp.Value'
colnames(transcriptome_reshape)[4]<- 'transcript_sd_data'
colnames(transcriptome_reshape)[5]<- 'sd.Time'
colnames(transcriptome_reshape)[6]<- 'sd.Value'

##2. Select ONE key target gene 
target_gene <- transcriptome_reshape %>%
  filter (Transcript %in% c('Kaladp0977s0008.1')) 

##3.Plot options

##plot whole genome
ggplot(data = transcriptome_reshape, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, group = Transcript)) +
  geom_line()

##plot target gene alone
ggplot(target_gene, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()

##plot all genes on same panel
select_genes_plot <- transcriptome_reshape %>%
  filter (Transcript %in% c('Kaladp0498s0001.1','Kaladp0011s0858.1','Kaladp0071s0450.1')) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, color = Transcript)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Transcript))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gene_exp.Value-sd.Value, ymax = gene_exp.Value+sd.Value), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.0))+
  geom_point(data = target_gene, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value), color = 'black', shape = 17)+ #this line plots target gene
  geom_line(data = target_gene, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, group=Transcript), color = 'black')+ #this line plots target gene
  geom_errorbar(data = target_gene, aes(ymin = gene_exp.Value-sd.Value, ymax = gene_exp.Value+sd.Value),color = 'black', width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.0))#this line plots target gene
  
select_genes_plot

##plot in facets
select_genes_plot_facets <- transcriptome_reshape %>%
  filter (Transcript %in% c('Kaladp0498s0001.1','Kaladp0011s0858.1','Kaladp0071s0450.1')) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, color = Transcript)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Transcript))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gene_exp.Value-sd.Value, ymax = gene_exp.Value+sd.Value), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.0))+
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(Transcript), ncol = 3)+
  geom_point(data = target_gene, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value), color = 'black', shape = 17)+ #this line plots target gene
  geom_line(data = target_gene, aes(x = gene_exp.Time, y = gene_exp.Value, group = 1), color = 'black')+ #this line plots target gene
  
select_genes_plot_facets
```

Comment: Please [don't use images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827), as they are pretty useless at accomplishing anything other then giving an impression. The preferred method of sharing data in R questions is by copy-pasting the output of `dput(example_data)` to your question.

Comment: The issue is that your `target_gene` dataset contains the faceting variable. Hence it is treated as a separate category. Try with dropping the `Transcript` variable from your `target_gene` dataset.